# resuse agg columns panda group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below contents in  csv file:

```
key1    key2    Key3    key4    key5

Val1    A        51     'True'  25
Val1    A        50     'False' 25
Val1    A        49     'True'  25
Val1    A        48     'True'  25
Val2    A        47     'False' 25
Val2    A        46     'True'  25
Val2    A        45     'False' 25
Val2    A        44     'True'  25
Val2    A        43     'True'  25
```

Output should be like:

```
key1 key2 max_key5 total_key4 total_true_key4 grade
Val1  A   51       4          3                1
Val2  A   47       5          3                2
```

I have to group by key1 and key2 then find the max of key5 and count of total rows of key4 and count of total true rows of key4 and then percentage.

What I am trying:

```
  grd = "1 if avg > 70 else 2 if avg > 50 else c"

    pct = lambda x: (1 if x > 70 else (2 if x > 50 else 3))



json_data
    .assign(_key4=lambda df_: df_['key4'] == "'True'")
    .groupby(['key1', 'key2'])
    .agg(
        maxkey5=('key5', 'max'), 
        total_key4=('key4', 'count'), 
        total_true_key4=('_key4', 'sum')
    )
   .eval('avg = (total_true_key4 * 100) / total_key4')
   .eval('feg = grd')
  #.apply(pct(avg))
```

eval to calculate percentage is working fine.. not able to do if else if on avg column

I don't want to apply separately like in another separate statement.

Comment: I do not see why you are getting `1,  2` for your grade column? Should n't`1` equals `2`? For `key1='val1'` your have three times `True` and four values in total..

Comment: Yes it was mistake there, it should be > 70 then 1 as total_true_key4 / total_key4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I am not quite sure how you would get your desired output with your logic. Also, you define `maxkey5=('key5', 'max')` but actually you are getting the `max` of `key3`. So, if I am not mistaken, you are looking for something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy import mean

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "key1": ["Val1"]*4+["Val2"]*5,
    "key2": ["A"]*9,
    "key3": [51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43],
    "key4": ["'True'", "'False'", "'True'", "'True'", "'False'", "'True'", "'False'", "'True'", "'True'"],
    "key5": [25] * 9
})


(
    df
    .assign(total_true_key4=df['key4']=="'True'", grade=df['key4']=="'True'")
    .groupby(["key1", "key2"])[["key3", "key4", "total_true_key4", "grade"]]
    .agg(
        {"key3": "max", 
         "key4": "count",
         "total_true_key4": "sum",
         "grade": lambda x: 1 if mean(x)>.7 else (2 if mean(x)>.5 else 3)}
    )
    .rename(columns={"key3":"max_key5", "key4":"total_key4"}).reset_index()
)
```

which results into the following data frame:

```py
   key1   key2  max_key5  total_key4  total_true_key4  grade
0  Val1   A     51        4           3                1
1  Val2   A     47        5           3                2
```

---

### EDIT

IIUC, you want to use your logic and just assign your grade column **directly** after defining your `avg` column. The way to achieve this is given below:

```py
bins = [0, 50, 70, 100]
labels = [3, 2, 1]

(
    df
    .assign(_key4=lambda df_: df_['key4'] == "'True'")
    .groupby(['key1', 'key2'])
    .agg(
        maxkey5=('key5', 'max'), 
        total_key4=('key4', 'count'), 
        total_true_key4=('_key4', 'sum')
    )
   .eval('avg = (total_true_key4 * 100) / total_key4')
   .assign(grade=lambda x: pd.cut(x.avg, bins, labels=labels))
)
```

Output:

```
               maxkey5  total_key4  total_true_key4  avg    grade
key1    key2                    
Val1    A      25        4           3               75.0   1
Val2    A      25        5           3               60.0   2
```

I did not change anything in your logic, besides of the last `assign` statement, where I assigned a new variable named `grade` using your evaluated `avg` column and the `pd.cut` method for pre-defined labels and bins.

Comment: I need to calculate percentage of total_true_key4 / total_key4 and have a column with grade depending on condition given above

Comment: maxkey5=('key5', 'max') is the maximum of key3

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, I have adjusted my code, please have a look. Now, I exactly achieve your expected output. If you want the max of `key5` instead of `key3`, you can do so by changing `key3` to `key5`.

Comment: I am getting error Must provide 'func' or tuples of '(column, aggfunc).

Comment: I have added 'grade' : lambda x: 1 if mean(x)>.8 else (2 if mean(x)>.5 else 3) in my code additionally and mean I am using from statistics

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, perfect. Yeah, you can also use your `.agg()` approach and work with tuples instead of dict. So, can I assume your problem is solved? And regarding the error, which `pandas` version are you using?

Comment: I m still facing the error, and pandas version is 1.3.5

Comment: What I am really looking is how to reuse the calculate column   "total_true_key4": "sum", I want to reuse total_true_key4 again for new column calculation

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, I think I finally understood your problem (also thanks to your edited post). I will edit my answer as well.

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, does this solve your problem?

Comment: Can we use like this grade = lambda x: if x.avg >50 else (2 if x.avg > 19 else 3) in last assign function

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, of course. You just have to adjust the variable `bins`  to `bins = [0, 19, 50, 100]`. Have a look at the documentation of [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). It replaces simple `if-else` statements.

Comment: but giving else condition giving me syntax error

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, ah you mean you want to use your `lambda` function that includes `if-else` statements instead of `pd.cut`. Unfortunately, that will not work.. you can indeed combine `lambda` +  `assign` but if you add `if-else` statements, you will compare several values with your single values which raises an error. Maybe there is a workaround for that but I am not aware of any. I think `pd.cut` is generally faster than `apply` with row-wise `if-else` conditions. Therefore, it may be worthwhile to use `pd.cut` column-wise.

Comment: Ok, just one thing.. for 0 its saying NAN

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, yeah, it is because `pd.cut` uses the specified intervals as left-open and right-closed. To include 0 for grade 3, you must just put in a small negative number instead of zero. For instance: `bins = [-1e-10, 50, 70, 100]`

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
json_data
    .assign(_key4=lambda df_: df_['key4'] == "'True'")
    .groupby(['key1', 'key2'])
    .agg(
        maxkey5=('key5', 'max'), 
        total_key4=('key4', 'count'), 
        total_true_key4=('_key4', 'sum')
        percentage=('key4', lambda x: int(sum(x)/len(x)*100))
    )
```

Comment: `lambda x: sum(x) / len(x)` is just `mean`